# Creating a view that display all records that belongs_to an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a view that display all records that belongs to an association and not sure on how to go about this.

I've created an erb file in view/members/showmembers.html.erb, added 'showmembers' method in members_controller.rb but when I go to http://localhost:3000/members/showmembers it says *'Couldn't find Member with id=showmembers'* and its pointing to the show method in the controller *'app/controllers/members_controller.rb:29:in `show'*.

```
  def showmembers    
    @organization = Organization.find(1)
    @shmembers = @organization.members.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @members }
    end
  end
```

showmembers.html.erb

```
    <% @shmembers.each do |shmember| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= shmember.id %></td>
        <td><%= shmember.first_name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error indicates that Rails don't know which action to use to process this request : http://localhost:3000/members/showmembers.

and since this request is "GET", Rails chose the "show" action.

so the solution is simply edit your config/routes.rb, and add this route:

```
resources :members do 
  collection do
    get :showmembers  # add this line 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please paste this into your route file otherwise it map to show action that cause this error please define route first\

```
     resources :members do 
      collection do
         get :showmembers  
      end 
     end
```

And then in controller

```
        hmembers = @organization.members
```

no need to this       members = @organization.members.all

If you define association well....